# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable with win32com interfacing with Attachmate

Tags: python, win32com, attachmate-extra

I'm using Python to try to automate Attachmate - EXTRA!, similar to how most do in VBA.

I'm using the package pywin32 found [here.](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32)
I'm using the documentation of how OLE works with Attachmate (where both GetString and PutString methods can be found) [here.](http://docs.attachmate.com/extra/x-treme/apis/com/methodsreference_des.htm)

My code:

```
system = win32com.client.Dispatch("EXTRA.System")
sess0 = system.ActiveSession

product = sess0.screen.GetString(0, 1, 2)
```

Produces the error:

```
line13: product = sess0.screen.GetString(1, 1, 2)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The method GetString, is said to have syntax: `rc = object.GetString (Row, Col, Length, [Page])`, but my above attempt at this syntax in Python produces the error above.

I've researched this error and found that it's the equivalent of trying to do: "mystring"(). This shouldn't be, because when I check the type of my sess0 it indeed is a: `<class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'>`.

I know this problem may stem from the syntax being different than what is explained on the Attachmate/OLE page. However, the PutString method is explained  to have this syntax: `object.PutString String [,Row][,Col][,Page]`, but I got it working fine using: `sess0.screen.PutString("90", 1, 79)`. That code correctly puts the string "90" at location 1, 79 in my Attachmate session.

I'm curious if maybe this is an issue with the package itself. If anyone has experience trying to automate Attachmate with Python, their help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you replace `sess0 = system.ActiveSession` with `sess0 = system.ActiveSession()` ? I think the problem could be that the object is not instantiated.

Comment: Wow that's interesting, when I do that, it errors out even earlier on when I send the F1 key to Attachmate: sess0.screen.SendKeys("<pf1>")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'screen'. When I had it with no parenthesis, this properly send the F1 command to my Attachmate session. With the parenthesis added, print(type(sess0)) returns <class 'str'>

Comment: Can you point me to the reference docs for `win32com.client.Dispatch` please?

Comment: And can you also print the output of what you get when you do `dir(sess0)`? It will list all the properties and methods available for the `sess0` object.

Comment: I have two suggestions (not solutions), how I approach similar issues: 1. Try to do the same in VBA and see what happens, and 2. win32com.client is still a python file (under site-packages somewhere). You can try to find where the exception is thrown (and why), because it looks like a pure client exception - not a COM exception thrown on the server-side.

Comment: @kiran: The dispatch interface is not very transparent and doesn't know about its methods from the COM server. So dir(sess0) will only report some builtin functions, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately most of the documentation seems to have been taken down, I got started here though: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/generate-a-static-com-proxy.html
When I leave the parenthesis out of system.ActiveSession and do print(type(sess0)) it returns <class 'win32com.client.CDispatch'> which is correct. I am able to send it F keys and use the PutString method. The dir print is too long for this box and unfortunately pastebin is blocked here at my job but it doesn't show the methods I'm trying to use.

Comment: @ Dr. V I am copying my existing code from VBA that does already work. I will try to find where and why the exception is thrown.. I don't know too much about Python but it is definitely time to learn :). Thank you both for your help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use these functions to read and write on an Attachmate EXTRA! Screen

Try the following:

```
import win32com.client

def write(screen,row,col,text):
    screen.row = row
    screen.col = col
    screen.SendKeys(text)


def read(screen,row,col,length,page=None):
    if page is None:
        return screen.Area(row, col, row, col+length).value
    else:
        return screen.Area(row, col, row, col+length, page).value


def test():
    system = win32com.client.Dispatch("EXTRA.System")
    sess0 = system.ActiveSession
    screen = sess0.Screen

    product = read(screen, 1, 1, 2)
    print(product)
    write(screen, 1, 79, "90")
```

#### Documentation:

[Screen.Area(StartRow,StartCol,EndRow,EndCol[,Page][,Type])](http://docs.attachmate.com/extra/x-treme/apis/com/areamethod_con.htm)

[SendKeys(String)](http://docs.attachmate.com/extra/x-treme/apis/com/sendkeysmethod_con.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up using the "Select" method, but this works excellent and I enjoy reading through your code and seeing someone else using Attachmate and Python. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @lightningblah Thank you! I'm trying to use the `WaitHostQuiet` method with optional `SettleTime` parameter, like this `screen.WaitHostQuiet (1000)`, but it's not working for me. Do you use this method? Could you explain how you use it in Python, please? 

I'm following the documentation in this [page](http://docs.attachmate.com/extra/x-treme/apis/com/waithostquietmethod_con.htm)

Comment: Hi AleGR. I assume you want to wait for the screen to update before you move on to your next command? The best way I've found is:

Comment: while screen.OIA.XStatus != 0:
     pass
Give that a try.